# Why does `-(num)**(even_number)` give `-(num^(even_number))` as result?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is something weird I noticed.

Any particular reason why -5**2 gives -25 and math.pow(-5,2) gives 25? The answer should be 25. So what is the reason for the -25 answer?

```
>>> -5**2
-25
>>> -5**4
-625
>>> 5**2
25
>>> 5**4
625
>>> import math
>>> pow(-5,2)
25
>>> pow(-5,4)
625
>>>
```

Comment: Simple answer: Order of operations

Comment: Please don't post images as code, [See this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332).

Comment: @BhargavRao - Will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: One quick note, you don't need to `import math`, `pow` is a built-in function.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - Thanks for the edit. And I'm new to Python. Hence, I didn't know that I needn't import the math module. Thanks for dropping in that note.

Comment: @MayankChoudhary we are all new at some point, this is how we learn.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - True! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow) for `math.pow` specifies that it raises `x` to the power of `y`.

So, `math.pow` calculates `(-5)**4`. whereas just writing `-5**4` is equivalent to `-1 * 5 **4`, since by operator precedence in Python the unary operator `-` has less precedence than the power operator `**`.

Answer (score 4):

In Python the `**` operator has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) than the `-` operator, so in your expression `5 ** 2` is evaluated first, then negated.  You can apply negation first by using brackets:

```
>>> -5**2
-25
>>> (-5)**2
25
```

Answer (score 3):

This is all explained [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator)

> The power operator binds more tightly than unary operators on its left; it binds less tightly than unary operators on its right.
>
> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): -1**2 results in -1.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the operator precedence in python.

If we look at the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), we see that the unary operator `-x` has lower precedence than the power operator `x**y`, so that the expression `-5**2` means to first apply the square to the 5 and then apply the negative sign to the result.  This first operation gives 25, which then gives -25.

The expression `math.pow(-5,2)` means to square the -5.  This is equivalent to `(-5)**2`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of that the precedence of `-` operator is lower than power operator `**`. In fact your expression will be calculated as following:

```
>>> -(5 ** 2)
```

Try the following to get the correct result:

```
>>> (-5) ** 2
25
```

For more information you can read the [python Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, from lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most binding).

[image]